# how to post selected check box with each text box value

Tags: php, html

[image]

i want insert  post text box values of each selected check boxes to the database.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $actions_to_be[$z]['student_email'] ?>"  />
<input type="text" name="timetable_id[]" value="<?php echo $actions_to_be[$z]['timetable_id'] ?>" size="10px"/>
<input type="text" name="sid[]" value="<?php echo $actions_to_be[$z]['sid'] ?>" size="10px" />
```

Comment: Did you try anything?Where you stuck?

Comment: i tried. i can get selected check box values. but cant get each text box value for selected check box row  .

Comment: check your post with print_r($_POST);

Comment: i checked, it send all text box values not selected one

Comment: that is not possible,All values should posted.You just think what logic behind your question.What is the relation between text box and checkbox

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"  />
<input type="text" name="timetable_id[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $actions_to_be[$z]['timetable_id'] ?>" size="10px"/>
<input type="text" name="sid[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $actions_to_be[$z]['sid'] ?>" size="10px" />
```

`$i` should be increased for every box of course. Then you can simply take the ids from the `$_POST['email']` array (possibly rename it to something more meaningful though) and retrieve the values in `$_POST['timetable_id'][$id]` and `$_POST['sid'][$id]`.